# Using Text Box Value as the 'Where' clause in SQL query

Tags: swing, javadb

I'm using javadb(netbeans) for a project and I am a total beginner.

I have a small app which searches an address database and brings back a data grid of results.

The users tpyes in all, or part of a street name into a jtextfield, hits a search button and the records are then filtered in a data grid.

I am writing simple sql queries which are working fine but I am strugging to indicate the where clause must be the jtextfield text. For example, what I need to do is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_addresses WHERE Street_Name = jTextfield.getstring()
```

but obiously that doesn't work. I also need to ensure this works as a wildcard query.

Can anybody help?? Please??

Comment: What does the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method. You have to use jTextField.getText () instead of jTextField.getString ()